How do I change the 'max-height' within 'max-h-80 overflow-y-hidden' with Tampermonkey?
I've been struggling with my first attempt at using Tampermonkey, obviously.
The bato.to comment section loads only the first 280 or so pixels of images on PC, which I'd like to about double to get closer to the mobile view most users have.
After finding the right variable to do that I've been now struggling to make the change permanent; Tampermonkey seems to be the easiest solution, but I'm not remotely familiar enough with the "new" F12 layout and website coding in general to make any of the user scripts I've been able to find work for this.
F12 view on the website
Basically, all I want to do, is, within
<div class="max-h-80 overflow-y-hidden">

to change
.max-h-80 {
    max-height: 20rem;

I was sadly yet of unable to find any help for as to how to make this work. max-height doesn't get accepted as a functioning variable, and the solutions I've found that use maxHeight instead don't function in actually changing the value on the website.

What you want to change is the style of the page aka CSS.
There are many ways to do this with Tampermonkey, the simplest way is GM_addStyle.
The important part is matching the correct window, in this case the comments are in their own iframe with a url like this: https://bato.to/embeds/comments?comicId=XXXXX&chapterId=XXXXXXX.
To match all urls of that format you can use: https://bato.to/embeds/comments*
// ==UserScript==
// @name         expand bato.to comments
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  .
// @author       You
// @match        https://mangatoto.com/embeds/comments*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=bato.to
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle('.max-h-80:not(.max-h-unset) { max-height: unset;}');


GM_addStyle inserts a new Style element with the css .max-h-80:not(.max-h-unset) { max-height: unset;}, this selector will match all the elements that have a class max-h-80 but NOT max-h-unset and sets their max-height to unset.
To set a specific max-height just change unset to any valid value, eg: max-height: 100rem;

I had to change the targeted URL and target it at the entire site, because it just didn't show up as a running script otherwise, but this worked perfectly, thank you!
// @match        https://mangatoto.com/*

@ArkiosShepard I see, I used  bato.to but same thing applies for mangatoto.com, if you want to target the comment iframe specifically you can use https://mangatoto.com/embeds/comments*

I tried it with that, it only works when targeting the entire site.

@ArkiosShepard that is strange, it works fine on my end. But It should not matter as long as it works.

Now that I've properly tested it, there's a major issue: this clamps the max-height at whatever value is set, even when the comment is visible instead of hidden. So, while the comment is being displayed fully it is always behind the other content. There seems to be a max-h-unset that is used whenever a comment is revealed, but gets bypassed by this script.

@ArkiosShepard see the edited answer with a new selector, this should fix it.

That did it. I had to shorten the targeted URL again, that part still doesn't work for me, but luckily the rest of the website uses max-h-28 so there's no interference. Gracious thanks, this time for real!

@ArkiosShepard no problem!
